# How to generate Random number based on range within List size without accessing zero

Tags: java, random

I have an Ant Colony Simulator. It is a 27 x 27 grid, and there is a Forager Ant class which locates food and the highest pheromone levels. I need to randomly generate the movement within a range.

This is a very large project, so here is only the method in question (if that's enough):

```
    private GridNode locateHighestPherms() {
    Random randomNode = new Random();
    LinkedList<GridNode> neighborNodeList = gridLocation.getNeighboringNodes(); //a List of Node Objects that keeps track of adjacent nodes
    LinkedList<GridNode> randomGridNode = new LinkedList<>(); //random destination Node

    for(Iterator<GridNode> gridNodeIterator = neighborNodeList.iterator(); gridNodeIterator.hasNext();) {
        GridNode alreadyVisited = gridNodeIterator.next();
        if(foragerMoveHistory.contains(alreadyVisited) || !alreadyVisited.isVisible()) {
            gridNodeIterator.remove();
        }
    }
    if(neighborNodeList.size() == 0) {
        neighborNodeList = gridLocation.getNeighboringNodes();
    }
    GridNode nodeWithMostPherms = neighborNodeList.get(0);

    for(int checkNode = 1; checkNode < neighborNodeList.size(); checkNode++) {
        if(nodeWithMostPherms.isVisible() && nodeWithMostPherms.getPheromoneUnit() < neighborNodeList.get(checkNode).getPheromoneUnit()) {
            nodeWithMostPherms = neighborNodeList.get(checkNode);
        }
    }
    for (GridNode neighborNode : neighborNodeList) {
        if ((neighborNode.getPheromoneUnit() == nodeWithMostPherms.getPheromoneUnit()) && neighborNode.isVisible()) {
            randomGridNode.add(neighborNode);
        }
    }
    //DEBUGGING
    //System.out.println(randomGridNode.size());
    nodeWithMostPherms = randomGridNode.get(randomNode.nextInt(randomGridNode.size()));
    //nodeWithMostPherms = randomGridNode.get(RandomInstance.randomNumberGen(1, randomGridNode.size()));
    return nodeWithMostPherms;
  }
}
```

Right there ^ the assignment to nodeWithMostPherms is where I need to access the next Random number. However, when I originally tried the code that's commented out, it was crashing because at times I was trying to access zero when the list size was zero.

I will show you my RandomInstance class. It's short and sweet:

```
    import java.util.Random;

public class RandomInstance {

static int randomNumber;

public static int randomNumberGen(int lowRange, int highRange) {

    Random numberGenerator = new Random(); //I would prefer not to have this.
    randomNumber = numberGenerator.nextInt(highRange - lowRange + 1) + lowRange;

    /** EXAMPLE FOR REFERENCE
     * setFoodUnitAmount(RandomInstance.randomNumberGen(500, 1000));
     */
    return randomNumber;
  }
}
```

The reason I have my own Random class is because there are **many** instances of random numbers that are generated, and it was suggested to create our own so we don't have a bunch of instances of java.util.Random all over the place.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how I can make this fit my RandomInstance class? 
If I try the code that's commented out, it throws an IndexOutOfBoundsException

```
    Exception in thread "Thread-0" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 8, Size: 8
at java.util.LinkedList.checkElementIndex(LinkedList.java:555)
at java.util.LinkedList.get(LinkedList.java:476)
at ForagerObject.locateHighestPherms(ForagerObject.java:121)
```

Line 121 is the assignment in question mentioned above.

Comment: Could you be more clear? What's wrong with having a java.util.Random instance variable inside your RandomInstance class?

Comment: Just by reading the title of the question we can get what you need... why posting so much confusing code then??

Comment: There's nothing wrong with having it inside that class. I'm referring to a situation where the class didn't exist, and I created many Randoms throughout the program.

Comment: And I included code because everyone is so random. One day someone says "Need more code", the next day someone says "Too much code you idiot!", and then I get rep taken away (does that even matter? This is a community, not a popularity contest). So, from one day to the next I have absolutely NO clue on how to please the StackOverflow Overlords.

Answer (score 1):

While you can have `Random` shared, you shouldn't share a multiple field.

```
public class RandomInstance {
    private final Random random = new Random();

    public int nextInt(int min, int max) {
        return random.nextInt(max - min + 1) + min;
    }
}
```

so when you call it

```
nodeWithMostPherms = randomGridNode.get(randomInstance.nextInt(1, randomGridNode.size()-1));
```

or you could use Random directly

```
nodeWithMostPherms = randomGridNode.get(random.nextInt(randomGridNode.size()-1)+1);
```